# converting number to string in matlab

Tags: matlab

is there a way to convert numbers to str in matlab

for example, 30120 turns into cat

where c is 03 a is 01 t is 20

here is my progress on RSA encryption/decryption I am trying to decrypt into plain text.

```
% variables

p=vpi('22953686867719691230002707821868552601124472329079')
q=vpi('30762542250301270692051460539586166927291732754961')
e=vpi('555799999999999');
n=(p.*q)
phi=((q-1).*(p-1))

% how to convert plaintext to integer mod 26


abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
word = 'acryptographicallystrongrandomnumbergeneratorwhichhasbeenproperlyseededwithadequateentropymustbeusedtogeneratetheprimespandqananalysiscomparingmillionsofpublickeysgatheredfromtheinternetwasrecentlycarriedoutbylenstrahughesaugierboskleinjungandwachteracryptographicallystrongrandomnumbergeneratorwhichhasbeenproperlyseededwithadequateentropymustbeused';  

[temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7,temp8,temp9] = split(word)

[int1,int2,int3,int4,int5,int6,int7,int8,int9] = intsplit(temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6,temp7,temp8,temp9)

[encrypt1, encrypt2, encrypt3, encrypt4, encrypt5, encrypt6, encrypt7, encrypt8, encrypt9] = encrypt_this(int1, int2, int3, int4, int5, int6, int7, int8, int9)

[decrypt1, decryt2, decrypt3, decrypt4, decryt5, decrypt6,decrypt7, decryt8, decrypt9] = decrypt_this(encrypt1, encrypt2, encrypt3, encrypt4, encrypt5, encrypt6, encrypt7, encrypt8, encrypt9)
```

Answer (score 1):

From 30120 to 'cat':

```
num = 30120;
l = ceil(numel(num2str(num))/2); % number of characters
num2 = sprintf('%06i', num);   % num in string form, with leading zero if needed
                               % '030120'
str = '';
for i = 1:l
    str = [str char(96+str2num(num2(2*i-1:2*i)))]; 
end % 96 is the ASCII offset needed to get a=1, c=3 etc like in your example
```

Results in `str = 'cat'`. I think that's what you want.

Comment: crud, so close except  sprintf command cannot handle vpi numbers is there a way around this? is there a way for me to convert vpi number to a number that is compatible with sprintf command

Comment: [the documentation for vpi](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic/content/VariablePrecisionIntegers/html/demo_vpi.html#5) states that you can convert it to struct and then access an array with the digit representation: `s = struct(vpi_number); s.digits;`